# Why Microsoft Sentinel alerts doesn't appear in graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-sentinel

Why when I query graph api to get all the security alerts, Microsoft sentinel alerts are not present. Is there some configuration to do ? I have the same result with both alerts and alerts_v2 endpoints.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why Microsoft Sentinel alerts doesn't appear in graph api?

To Get the list of alert v2 resources you need either **`SecurityAlert.Read.All`** or **`SecurityAlert.ReadWrite.All`** application permission needed.

In my environment, I created an application With the name **`testvenkat`**        and added  **`SecurityAlert.Read.All`** permission.

**Portal:**
[image]

Using the above application, I created an **`access-token`** with the client credential flow through Postman.

**Postman:**

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Now using the above access token I can able to get the security alerts v2 through endpoints.

**Postman:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[List alerts_v2 - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/security-list-alerts_v2?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Yes, I have seen. But the alerts that appear in response body are alerts from Defender (Security.microsoft.com/...). What I want is the alerts, from Sentinel  (portal.azure.com)

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securityinsights/alert-rule-templates/get?view=rest-securityinsights-2023-02-01&tabs=HTTP

Comment: Yes but it's for alert rule template so it's not for alert that were generated ? or m'I wrong ?